# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

Tags: ios, multithreading, signals, sigabrt

> Thread 1: signal SIGABRT
>
> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException'

What does this error indicate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of error usually occurs when you try to pass an invalid argument as a parameter of the function. For example: if function requires non-nil value, but your variable is nil. See Apple documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsinvalidargumentexception